# Angular Instantiating an EntryComponent Creates New Service

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

In my root component, app.component.ts, I have added a service to providers[] and declared it in the constructor:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [AccountService]
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor( accountService: AccountService ) {}
ngOnInit(){}
}
```

In my main app module, app.module.ts, I have an entryComponent which will eventually be the contents of a MatDialog:

```
// ....
entryComponents: [CompanyPreviewComponent]
```

When I open the dialog, a new copy of my AccountService is spun up. So now I have two instances of the same service, and anything I do to the service inside the dialog has no effect on the actual AccountService that the rest of my app relies on.

What is the best way to prevent this additional service from being created?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You should [Provide service](https://angular.io/guide/providers#providing-a-service) at `module` level instead of `component`, so that all the instances of a service share the same copy.

**Note** : *This is not true if you have components under lazy loading module that injects this service*

Providing service at module level can be achieved in two ways for latest angular versions:

1.Using `providedIn: AppModule` or `providedIn: 'root'`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: AppModule,
})
export class AccountService {
}
```

2.Providing directly inside the module

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ........
  ],
  .........
  providers: [AccountService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you add your service inside your component, it will be local to it component. So if you have two instance of your component, you will have two instance of your service.

if you provide your service inside your module, it will be global and if you have two instance of your component, they will share the same instance of the service.